# Pgadmin4: No module named 'idna'

Tags: pgadmin

Why do I get the error No module named 'idna' from Pgadmin4 when I try to save server properties?

[image: Pgadmin4: No module named 'idna']

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I'm running into this, as well. Installing `idna` via pip did not help.

Comment: same problem here